# Build a Docker Image from VisualStudio ASP.net project and use it on different docker host

Tags: docker, visual-studio, asp.net-core, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am stuck for days with creating a dockerimage of my asp.net core web api project.

Everything works in VisualStudio but I want to create/build the image to use it on different linux docker host.

I can see it maps some local windows folders and assign some folders also to the project path.
We don't have a Docker Hub or other Registry. So I thought I build the image and import it to our local linux host where docker is installed.

Should it not copy everything into the docker image?

How can this goal be achieved?

Thank you very much!

I have tried different dockerfiles. But I think I need some help to understand this process.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
#ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
USER app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
#ARG PASSWORD_ENV_SEEDED
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/API/API.csproj", "src/API/"]
COPY ["src/Application/Application.csproj", "src/Application/"]
COPY ["src/Domain/Domain.csproj", "src/Domain/"]
COPY ["src/Shared/Shared.csproj", "src/Shared/"]
COPY ["src/Client/Client.csproj", "src/Client/"]
COPY ["src/Client.Infrastructure/Client.Infrastructure.csproj", "src/Client.Infrastructure/"]
COPY ["src/Infrastructure/Infrastructure.csproj", "src/Infrastructure/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./src/API/./API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/API"
RUN dotnet build "./API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
#generate the cert, define the path to store it and password to use
#RUN dotnet dev-certs https -ep /https/aspnetapp.pfx -p ${PASSWORD_ENV_SEEDED}

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
#COPY --chmod=0755 --from=build /https/* /https/
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ApplicationName.API.dll"]
```

**Docker-Compose from VS**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  kemcalapp:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: src\API\Dockerfile
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    restart: on-failure
    container_name: APP
```

Comment: As you say, the normal way to do it is to use a registry. If that's not possible, you can export the image to a file using `docker image save` and `docker image load`. Or you can copy your Dockerfile and all dependencies to the other machine and build the image there.

Comment: Thank you. But when does it copy all files into the docker and don't map them?

Comment: Copying files into the *image* is done at build time. Mapping files into the *container* is done at run-time. Can you clarify your question as to what part of the process you're asking about?

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I have added some samples above. Thats also my understanding or the goal i want to archieve. 
At least I want to deploy the image with a bitbucket-pipeline. But before that I want to try it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker images are usually not transported from server A to server B *(like drag and drop or like some file be like)*, either you build them together with a Dockerfile or you pull them from a repo-server e.g. `hub.docker.com`.

Since you have a Dockerfile, you can upload this Dockerfile and your source code (just your whole project folder) to your other Docker server (via ftp, ssh or similar) and then build the image with the following command `docker build -t yourImageName .`

- `docker build`: This part of the command tells Docker to build a new image.
- `-t yourImageName`: The "-t" flag is used to tag the image with a name. In this case, "yourImageName". You can replace "yourImageName" with whatever name you prefer.
- `.`: The dot at the end of the command specifies the build context. It tells Docker to look for the Dockerfile in the current directory.

Normally, you should now see bars in the console that work from left to right, pulling, building or extracting your/other images.

Once the image has been built, it can be used normally as an example: `docker run -d --name myContainerName yourImageName` of course you can add other parameters like `-p` for port or `-v` for the volume mapping or how you did it in a docker compose file.

Comment: To do this, you'd also need to copy everything the Dockerfile needs. In this case, the source code.

Comment: Right, my bad. I'll edit this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I could finally build the image with

```
docker build -f .\src\API\Dockerfile -t appname .
```

and then export it as .tar with

```
docker save -o
```

I will now build my bitbucket-pipeline from the repo and save the file manually.